# Библиотека для работы с большими числами c#

Tags: c#, библиотеки, biginteger, длинная-арифметика

Я очень сильно хочу сделать свою библиотеку для работы с большими числами. Я начал ее делать. И понял что не знаю как ее сделать.

```
public struct BigInt
{
    private byte[] Value { get; set; }

    public BigInt(string value)
    {
        if (value.Length != 0)
            Value = new byte[value.Length];
        else
        {
            Value = null;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = value.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            Value[i] = (byte)value[i];
    }

    public BigInt(byte[] value) { this.Value = value; }

    public override string ToString() => Encoding.Default.GetString(Value);

    public static implicit operator BigInt(string num) => new BigInt(num);

    public static implicit operator string(BigInt num) => Encoding.Default.GetString(num.Value);

    public static string operator +(BigInt c1, BigInt c2) => Addition(c1.Value, c2.Value);

    public static string operator +(BigInt c1, string c2) => Addition(c1.Value, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(c2));

    public static string operator *(BigInt c1, BigInt c2) => Multiplication(c1.Value, c2.Value);

    public static string operator *(BigInt c1, string c2) => Multiplication(c1.Value, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(c2));

    public static string Addition(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
        int c = 0, d = 0;
        List<byte> z = new List<byte>();
        if(x.Length > y.Length)
        {
            z.InsertRange(0, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(new String('0', x.Length - y.Length).ToCharArray()));
            z.AddRange(y);
            y = z.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            z.InsertRange(0, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(new String('0', y.Length - x.Length).ToCharArray()));
            z.AddRange(x);
            x = z.ToArray();
        }
        for(int i = x.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            byte a = x[i];
            byte b = y[i];
            c = (d + (a % 48) + (b % 48)) % 10;
            result.Add((byte)c);
            d = (d + a % 48 + b % 48) / 10;
        }
        if (d != 0)
            result.Add((byte)d);
        result.Reverse();
        return string.Join("", result);
    }

    public static string Multiplication(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        List<byte>[] result = new List<byte>[y.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++)
        {
            int c = 0;
            int d = 0;
            List<byte> array = new List<byte>();
            for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
            {
                byte a = x[x.Length - 1 - j];
                byte b = y[y.Length - 1 - i];
                c = (d + (a % 48) * (b % 48)) % 10;
                array.Add((byte)c);
                d = (d + (a % 48) * (b % 48)) / 10;
            }
            if (d > 0)
                array.Add((byte)d);
            result[i] = array;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < result[i].Count / 2; j++)
            {
                byte temp = result[i][j];
                result[i][j] = result[i][result[i].Count - 1 - j];
                result[i][result[i].Count - 1 - j] = temp;
            }

        if (result.Length > 1)
            for (int i = 1; i < result.Length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < result.Length - i; j++)
                    result[j + i].Add((byte)0);

        if (result.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                List<byte> z = result[0];
                for (int j = 0; j < z.Count; j++)
                    z[j] += 48;
                result[0] = new List<byte>(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Addition(z.ToArray(), result[i + 1].ToArray())));
            }
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(result[0].ToArray());
        }
        return String.Join("", result[0]);
    }

    public static string Pow(string x, int degrees)
    {
        if (degrees == 0) return "1";
        if (degrees == 1) return x;
        byte[] result = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(x);
        byte[] num = result;
        for (int i = 2; i <= degrees; i++)
            result = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Multiplication(result, num));
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
    }

    public static string Factorial(int number)
    {
        if (number == 0) return "1";
        if (number <= 2) return number.ToString();
        byte[] result = Encoding.Default.GetBytes((6).ToString());
        for (int i = 4; i <= number; i++)
            result = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Multiplication(result, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(i.ToString())));
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
    }
}
```

Выше весь код до которого я додумался. И я уверен в том что этот код максимально плох.

Я хочу узнать чего нужно придерживаться когда пишешь такую библиотеку. (Например в чем хранить данные чтобы памяти меньше требовало или какие алгоритмы использовать для увеличения скорости работы)
Желательно еще пару примеров. (Можно на любых языках) Ну и литературу какую-нибудь чтобы потом вопросов меньше задавать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сам писал такое, могу дать следующие советы:

1. Не используйте десятичную систему для хранения данных, это очень далеко от оптимального. Нужно использовать `2^32` систему. Вместо массива байт число будет хранится в массиве `uint`. При этом вы оптимально используете память, и все операции операции в этой системе счисления будут очень быстрыми. При этом парсинг строк и метод `ToString` значительно усложнятся.
2. У вашем коде при перегрузке операторов вы возвращаете строки. Это неправильно. При длинной цепочке вызовов у вас постоянно будет число превращаться в строку и обратно. Если вы будете возвращать `BigInt`, тогда этого превращения не будет.
3. Для некоторых операций существуют неочевидные алгоритмы, которые работают быстрее. Например, стандартное умножение работает за `O(n^2)`, [умножение по алгоритму Карацубы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8B) работает за `O(n^1.58)`. Вам нужно экспериментальным путем определить, при каких значениях длины умножаемых чисел следует использовать один алгоритм, а при каких другой.
4. Нужно сократить операции выделения памяти к минимуму. Например, в умножении вы используете массив списков. Это очень много объектов в памяти, которые потом сборщик мусора будет очищать. Если вы умножаете число длиной `n` на число длиной `m`, то результат будет не длиннее чем `n + m`. Вы можете создать один массив такой длины и больше не создавать никаких объектов.
5. Изучайте код других библиотек, там всегда можно подсмотреть интересные идеи для оптимизаций. Сравнивайте быстродействие, ищите узкие места.

Мой BigInteger: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul/Math/BigInteger.cs

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! А можете пожалуйста ссылку на какой нибудь сайт скинуть ну или видео где объясняется что за система 2^32 и как с ней работать.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков я не читал об этом нигде, не знаю, описано ли где-то это. Но она ничем не отличается от других систем счисления. Вот примеры: двоичная: `9=1*2^3+0*2^2+0*2^1+1*2^0`, получаем `[1][0][0][1]`, 65-ная: `999=15*65^1+24*65^0`, получаем `[15][24]`. Система 2^32: `1234567890123=287*4294967296^1+1912276171*4294967296^0`. Получаем: `[287][1912276171]` - это и будет ваш массив `uint[]`.

Comment: А вот сложение или умножение как будет работать в массив uint[]?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков так же как и у вас с десятичной. Только цифры будут не от 0 до 9, а от 0 до 4294967295. Перед тем как работать с "цифрой", ее нужно скопировать в переменную типа `long` (что бы не было переполнения).

Comment: В плане скопировать в переменную типа long? Можете пожалуйста поподробней. И последний вопрос возник а есть ли какой нибудь быстрый алгоритм перевода из десятичной в 2^32

Comment: @ПавелЕриков ну вот вам суммируете 2 цифры в системе 2^32. Пишите: `long sum = (long)digits1[i] + (long)digits2[i]`. Где `digits` это `uint[]`. Без превращения к лонгу работать не будет. Так же само с умножением.

Comment: Все спасибо вроде все понял!

Answer (score 1):

Как-то мне тоже понадобилась длинная арифметика. Но использовать GMP было нельзя, так как длинная арифметика нужна была для микроконтроллеров без операционной системы и кучи. Пришлось написать свою библиотеку С++ шаблонов для работы с длинными целыми числами. Вот ссылка:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/muntl/?source=frontpage&position=5

Там в архиве есть и описание на русском языке.